# Dynamically change price range in jquery ui slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui

I am trying to working price range using jquery slider,
This is how it works,

When user selects slider and adjusts one side of the slider the value in the slider passes to my controller and executes, it by adding the params to url and refreshing the page.

Whats going wrong:
When user adjusts the any one side of the slider, the params are going correctly and executing correctly, but **after refreshing the page, the slider range values going to default values, which i don't want**, i want them according to the param values(price_min, price_max)

```
var PropertyPriceFilter = { min:100000, max:10000000 };
     $("#filtered-price").val((PropertyPriceFilter.min) + " - " + (PropertyPriceFilter.max));


        $("#property_price").slider({

            range:true,
            min:PropertyPriceFilter.min,
            max:PropertyPriceFilter.max,

            values:[ 100000, 10000000 ], //dynamically change values using values present in the params["price_min"] & params["price_max"]
              slide:function (event, ui) {
                $("#filtered-price").val(("Rs." + ui.values[ 0 ]) + " - " + "Rs." + (ui.values[ 1 ]))
                PropertyPriceFilter.min = ui.values[ 0 ]
                PropertyPriceFilter.max = ui.values[ 1 ]

            window.location += '&price_min=' + PropertyPriceFilter.min + '&price_max=' + PropertyPriceFilter.max;
        }
    });
```

__*_*__This is the if else conditions for the values to change from params, there are logically correct, but still not working, i don't know why

```
if ((params["price_min"] != null) || (params["price_max"] != null))
{

    if ((params["price_min"] != null) && (params["price_max"] = null)) {
        var price_min = parseInt(params["price_min"])
        var price_max = 10000000
    }
    else if ((params["price_min"]) = null && (params["price_max"]) != null) {
        var price_min = 100000
        var price_max = parseInt(params["price_max"])
    }
    else if ((params["price_min"]) != null && (params["price_max"]) != null) {
        var price_min = parseInt(params["price_min"])
        var price_max = parseInt(params["price_max"])
    }
}
else
{
    var price_min = 100000
    var price_max = 10000000
}
```

Comment: I'm confused: Your use of params suggest that your 2nd code snippet is server side ruby code, yet you are also using "var" and "parseInt" which suggests it's javascript.  I don't understand how this hybrid is working....

Comment: Both the snippets are from the .js.erb file, where javascript and ruby both works. My questions is how to change the values of min , max dynamically using params

Comment: I've never seen .erb files work like that.  Can you please paste in, or link to, the actual generated source code.

Comment: Thats not file.js.erb, its file.js only. And my problem has been solved. I made logical mistake, it should not be params["price_max"] = null),it has to be params["price_max"] == null). params is a javascript method